# Mask Numpy Array by specified months

Tags: python, numpy, date

If i have the following list

```
import numpy as np
import datetime
a = [datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 13, 0, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2012, 6, 29, 0, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 28, 0, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2011, 4, 21, 0, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2011, 9, 18, 0, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 15, 0, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 12, 0, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 11, 0, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 9, 0, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 15, 0, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 7, 0, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 5, 0, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 2, 0, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 10, 0, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 7, 0, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 3, 0, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 11, 0, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 9, 0, 0)]
```

I need to find the indices for elements contain months between Jan-May and October-Dec.

My initial attempt is a follows:

```
b =[i.strftime("%m") for i in dates]
b = np.array(b).astype(int)
idx = np.argwhere((b<6) | (b>9))
d_a = np.array(a)
result = d_a[idx]
```

Witch returns the desired `result`:

```
array([[datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 28, 0, 0)],
       [datetime.datetime(2011, 4, 21, 0, 0)],
       [datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 15, 0, 0)],
       [datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 12, 0, 0)],
       [datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 9, 0, 0)],
       [datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 7, 0, 0)],
       [datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 2, 0, 0)],
       [datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 7, 0, 0)],
       [datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 3, 0, 0)],
       [datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 9, 0, 0)]], dtype=object)
```

Can this be improved/simplified to not use list comprehension?

Comment: The list comprehension is probably best.  `numpy` has a `datetime64` dtype, but pulling the month (across all years) isn't trivial.  It doesn't have the equivalent of the `strftime` methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to get `result`, you can do the following without getting indices of searching elements:

```
a_arr = np.array(a)
filter_func = np.vectorize(lambda x: True if x.month not in [6, 7, 8, 9] else False)
result = a_arr[filter_func(a_arr)]
```

But if you would like to get indices of searching elements you can get them by this way:

```
indices = np.where(filter_func(a_arr))
```